# Adding if user is guest/customer statement to PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to edit some PHP code so that the cart appears on the checkout page for certain users only. I need it to appear for guests, customers, and admins. I know very little about PHP, but the code is throwing an error.

This is the original code I started with, and wanted to add an if statement so it shows up for certain users only:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only', 5 );

function bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only() {

if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');

}
```

This is the code I am trying that is not working:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only', 5 );

function bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only() {

if ( Auth::guest() || current_user_can('customer') || current_user_can('Administrator' ) && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return; 

echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');

}
```

Ther error code is the following:

> [30-Oct-2019 16:45:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Auth' not found in
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php:100
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only(Object(WC_Checkout)) 1
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 2
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 3
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php(22): do_action('woocommerce_bef...', Object(WC_Checkout)) 4
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(249):
>   include('/home/ropehound...') 5
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(285):
>   wc_get_template('checkout/form-c...', Array) 6
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(67):
>   WC_S in
>   /home/ropehound/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php
>   on line 100

Comment: What error? What issues are you facing?

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. And "an error" isn't a useful description of the error either. We can't guess what it is - you need to tell us. Don't forget we cannot read your screen, your disk...or your mind. Thanks.

Comment: `Auth::guest() && current_user_can('customer')` are you sure you meant `&&`?

Comment: You mixing OR with AND condition it's the problem i'll thing try something like : 

if ( Auth::guest() && (current_user_can('customer') || current_user_can('Administrator' ) ) && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

Comment: I do mean || not && between guest and customer. That is one mistake. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: The error read that the class `Auth` is not defined, so you cannot call `Auth::guest()` without loading the `Auth` class first.